# How to iterate over Javolution FastMap

Tags: loops, javolution

Using the Javolution 6.0.0 Snaphot from February.

According to this we can iterate over the FastMap, but I keep getting an java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/util/FastMap.html

My code

```
FastMap<String,String> map = new FastMap<String, String>();
map.put("1", "2");

for (FastMap.Entry<String, String> m : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = m.getKey();
    String value = m.getValue();
}
```

Further more from the samples explained in the link...
map.head and map.tail don't even exist.

So then how do we do it?

Answer (score -2):

The February snapshot version was not ready for release. Now that the official 6.0.0 is out, everything should work fine.